# MFRC522 reading/wrting old RFID tags

Tags: rfid, mfrc522

I can successfully read and write the (1k) tags that came with the reader, but the tags I need to use have just 4 bytes per block rather than the 16 for the 1k tags, and presumably no security. The data sheet for the reader chip is rather useless (I am going cross eyed looking at it) and the available code for using it does not suggest what settings need changing to read these old tags.  Question. Should I be able to read (I am guessing) Type 2 tags with this reader, and any body got any documentation that might help me make the NXP chip (Chinese clone) read 4 bytes instead of 16?
thanks in advance.
P

Answer (score 0):

So no, the tag reader module only reads/writes a 16 byte "block".  With block 0 being immutable. The tags I have are "striped" with each 4 bytes being repeated 4 times (with an offset of 1).  There you go.